# ASP.NET Azure Web App Pipeline: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The following is my YAML:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'mySubscription'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'mySiteName'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

```
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

I've even tried changing `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` in the `AzureWebApp` task to no avail.

Comment: just a guess, but the error is looking like a windows directory structure (using backslashes) and the package is using linux directory structure (forward slashes) in the YAML file. Try using backslases in the package location. I'm not sure if backslashes need to be escaped in Azure, you may need to use double backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current situation, I have some suggestions might help you solve this issue:

1. Please check the 'Enable system diagnostics' option when you run
   your pipeline then check your build task and check if the zip file
   has been created successfully and find the zip file folder.
2. Please go to the pipeline UI page and check if you can find the
   artifact file on the page, also please make sure the zip file has
   been included.

If you can find the zip file in your artifact. Then we can modify your yaml file like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
stages:
  - stage: generate
    jobs:
      - job: Job_1
        displayName: job_Create_Zip
        steps:
        - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

        - task: VSBuild@1
          inputs:
            solution: '$(solution)'
            msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
            platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

        - task: VSTest@2
          inputs:
            platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
            artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'
  - stage: 
    jobs:
      - job: Job_2
        displayName: Deploy_zip 
        steps:
        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'
            itemPattern: '**/*.zip'
            targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        - task: AzureWebApp@1
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'mySubscription'
            appType: 'webApp'
            appName: 'mySiteName'
            package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
            deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `VSBuild` task output, you should see a line saying:

> Package "{your_project_name}.zip" is successfully created as single file at the following location:
> file:///D:/a/1/a

`D:/a/1/a` in the above above example comes from `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"` parameter that you pass to msbuild (which is different than DefaultWorkingDirectory: `D:\a\1\s\`).

So your `AzureWebApp` task has to look inside `$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)`. Make sure these paths match.